# Dimension reduction for logical arrays

Tags: matlab, pca, dimension-reduction

I have measurements of 5 devices at two different points of time. A measurement basically consists of an array of ones and zeros corresponding to a bit value at the corresponding location:

```
whos measurement1_dev1_time1

Name                         Size               Bytes  Class      Attributes

measurement1_dev1_time1      4096x8             32768  logical
```

I assume that for a specific device the changes between time 1 and 2 of the measurements are unique. However, since I am dealing with 32768 bits at different locations, it is quite hard to visualize if there is some kind of dependency.

As every bit at location `x`can be regarded as one dimension of an observation I thought to use PCA to reduce the number of dimensions.

Thus, for every of the 5 devices:

1. I randomly sample `n` measurements at point `t1`and `t2` seperatly
2. I prepare an array as input for `pca()` with `m`*n columns (`m`< 32768; its a subset of all the observed bits, as the original data might be too big for pca) and 4 rows (one row for each device).
3. On this array `A` I calculate the pca: ``[coeff score latent] = pca(zscore(A))```
4. Then I try to visualize it using `biplot`: `biplot(coeff(:,1:2), 'score', score(:,1:2))`

However, this gives me really strange results. Maybe PCA is not the right approach for this problem? I also modified the input data to do the PCA not on the logical bit array itself. Instead, I created a vector, which holds the indices where there is a '1' in the original measurement array. Also this produces strange results.

As I am completely new to PCA I want to ask you if you either see a flaw in the process or if PCA is just not the right approach for my goal and I better look for other dimension reduction approaches or clustering algorithms.

Comment: maybe try here: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will repost there!

Comment: There are 5 devices (even though the number can be increased). I updated the original thread.

Answer (score 1):

Can this 'some kind of dependency' be just pairwise correlation of your data points? Or what do you want to find out?

Do you get 'expected results' if you do:

```
meas_norm = 2*measurement1_dev1_time1 - 1;

CovarianceMatrix = meas_norm' * meas_norm;

figure
pcolor(CovarianceMatrix )
```

Can there be a problem of data type? Try feeding `double(data)`. (Please add proper code into your example)

if you look for dimension reduction, you can also think about [ICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis).

---

UPD: 
can you probe it with `xor`? As you cannot do `xor` on rows or columns, you can trick `all(x, dimension)`

```
example = imread('cameraman.tif')>128;

meas_points = numel(example);
num_sensors = 4;

%// simulate data for t1
meas_before = repmat(example(:), 1, num_sensors);
flickering_before = (rand(meas_points, num_sensors)<0.001);
meas_before(flickering_before) = ~meas_before(flickering_before);

%// simulate position of changing pixels, let's say 8%
true_change = (rand(num_sensors,1)<0.08);

%// simulate data for t2    
meas_after = repmat(example(:), 1, num_sensors);
meas_after(true_change) = ~meas_after(true_chage);
flickering_after = (rand(meas_points, num_sensors)<0.001);
meas_after(flickering_after) = ~meas_after(flickering_after);

stable_points_after = all(meas_after, 2) | all(~meas_after, 2);
stable_point_fraction = sum(stable_points_after)./ meas_points;

%// similarly for the states before (i.e. t1)
stable_points_before = all(meas_before, 2) | all(~meas_before, 2);   

%// now see which change coherently
stable_chage = meas_after(stable_points_after, 1) & meas_before(stable_points_before, 1)
```

Comment: The correlation I expect is the following: given a particular device and n measurements at time t more then 90% of the bits at their individual position will be the same for the n measurements (thus, there will be 10% noise, which are bit flips). However, the position of the stable bits as well as their preferred value (0 or 1) will change from t1 to t2 for the devices individually. I want to visualize this uniqueness of the changes.

Thus, you code using the CovarianceMatrix does not express what I want to express.

I will look into ICA and add some code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It depends on what you are referring to as pairwise correlation between my data points: indeed the expected correlation is always between the i-th data point of a measurement at point t1 and the i-th data point of a measurement at point t2. However, only looking at all the data points reveals the characteristics between t1 and t2, which are unique for a single device.

Comment: There are is a problem with the updated code: stable_points_before is undefined. Should it be:

stable_points_before = all(meas_before, 2) | all(~meas_before, 2);

Comment: exactly, like for '*after'